# neo4j-2.2.5.pom cannot be read of is not a valid zip file error

Tags: gradle, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

After I updated spring-data-neo4j to latest version: 4.0.0.RELEASE, I am getting the java build path error as follows:

> 'C:/Users/UserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.neo4j/neo4j/2.2.5/c7c8174f5a175a96686a461033a9f7e01d24df1d/neo4j-2.2.5.pom'
>   in project 'movements-jhipster-neo4j-4-issue' cannot be read or is not
>   a valid ZIP file  movements-jhipster-neo4j-4-issue        Build path  Build
>   Path Problem

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release"}
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE')
        classpath('com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.10')
        classpath('com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.10')
    }
}



apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility=1.7
targetCompatibility=1.7
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'





bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.movements.jhipster.Application'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.movements.jhipster.Application'
}

bootRun {
    addResources = false
}

apply from: 'yeoman.gradle'


apply from: 'gatling.gradle'


if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'profile_prod.gradle'
} else if (project.hasProperty('fast')) {
    apply from: 'profile_fast.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'profile_dev.gradle'
}

group = 'com.movements.jhipster'
version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ''

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release"
        maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-core'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-graphite'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-healthchecks'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-jvm', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlet', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-json', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlets'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-json-org', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hppc', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate4', version: jackson_version
    compile (group: 'com.ryantenney.metrics', name: 'metrics-spring', version: metrics_spring_version) {
        exclude(module: 'metrics-core')
        exclude(module: 'metrics-healthchecks')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP-java6') {
        exclude(module: 'tools')
    }
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: commons_lang_version
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: commons_io_version
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: javax_inject_version
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'javax.transaction-api'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time'
    compile group: 'org.apache.geronimo.javamail', name: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail', version: geronimo_javamail_1_4_mail_version
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-loader-tools'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop'

    //Neo4j
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:4.0.0.RELEASE' //3.3.2.RELEASE'

    //Mongo
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.0.RELEASE' 
    //Redis
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-redis'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:1.6.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-localconfig-connector'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support') {
        exclude(module: 'quartz')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: spring_security_oauth2_version
    compile group: 'org.mongeez', name: 'mongeez', version: mongeez_version
    compile(group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: springfox_version)
    compile(group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: springfox_version){
        exclude module: 'org.mapstruct.mapstruct'
    }




    //AWS
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.10.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:1.0.1.RELEASE'

    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: awaility_version
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: assertj_core_version
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core'
    testCompile group: 'cz.jirutka.spring', name: 'embedmongo-spring', version: embedmongo_spring_version
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library'
    testCompile group: 'io.gatling.highcharts', name: 'gatling-charts-highcharts', version: gatling_version

    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2'

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

task stage(dependsOn: 'bootRepackage') {
}
```

Comment: Please share with us your pom.xml

Comment: @MicTech I have updated question with build.gradle content. Please have a look.

Comment: can you check the actual pom.xml in your local cache? Sometimes ISP's intercept DNS and you get a garbage html page instead of the pom. If so you have to delete the wrong one.